# How to create multiple Pandas time series from a data frame using python?

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, dataframe

I am starting with a Pandas data frame that looks like this:

```
   Type Date Number
1   A    x     y
2   B    x     y
3   A    x     y
4   B    x     y
5   A    x     y
```

I want to create separate time series for Type A data and Type B data separately. What is the most efficient way of doing this?

I am considering creating two different data frames from this where each data from only has data from one type and then converting each of the separate data frames to a series. However I don't know how to do this either.

Extended question: Is there a way to do this if you don't even know how many different types there are?

So far I tried checking to see if the type is of the type I want by using `df["type"] == A`, and this doesn't give me a full data frame back just a data frame saying if the type was true or false.

Additional information:

My goal is to create separate pandas time series using the date and number data for type `A` and type `B` separately.

I tried the following:

```py
df.groupBy("Type").apply(lambda x: x.Date)
```

The above function works but only returns one column.

```py
df.groupBy("Type").apply(lambda x: (x.Date, x.Number))
```

The above function doesn't work and returns something that is not what I want at all.

Expected Output:

```
Type    Date Number
 A   1   x     y
     3   x     y
     5   x     y
 B   2   x     y
     4   x     y
```

Comment: Please add an expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to group dates by type and put them into a separate Series, you can do the following.

Group by type:
`grouped = df.groupby('Type')`

Get the date from every group:
`dates = grouped.apply(lambda x:x.Date)`

`dates` now looks like this:

```
Type   
A     1    x
      3    x
      5    x
B     2    x
      4    x
```

You can access Series by type name: `dates.A, dates.B` etc

> So far I tried checking to see if the type is of the type I want by using df["type"] == A, and this doesn't give me a full data frame back just a data frame saying if the type was true or false.

`df["type"] == A` gives you a boolean mask which you can plug back into a dataframe: `df[df["type"] == A]`
But this is a very basic pandas operation, take a look at the official tutorial, there are a lot of examples: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/tutorials.html

Comment: This is helpful! How do I get dates to have 3 columns including one for the x and one for the y?? I want to create a time series for the dates which are in x and the numbers which are in y.

Comment: I tried this: grouped.apply(lambda x: [x.Date, x.Number]) and it didn't work.

Comment: Can you post an example how should output look like?

Comment: I posted some additional information above! Basically my end goal is to have 2 time series with date and the number information for each group separately. I'm not actually totally sure what a time series looks like.

Comment: I added what I wanted the output to look like.

Comment: Inspect the contents of `list(grouped)`